# Priority on lemniscate of Gerono?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, geometry, differential-geometry

The [Lemniscate of Gerono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Gerono) is a special case of the [Lissajous curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve).  The dates for the two mathematicians are fairly close: [Gerono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camille-Christophe_Gerono) (1799-1891) and [Lissajous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jules_Antoine_Lissajous) (1822-1880). Historically who has priority for the lemniscate?  Was Lissajous aware of Gerono's work when he introduced his curves?

Comment: According to French wikipedia "Gerono's lemniscate is a plane curve studied by Grégoire de Saint-Vincent in 1647, next by Gabriel Cramer en 1750". Perhaps the question is when or why did it get this name. Lissajous' work is online (35p.), no mention.

Comment: Gerono may not have been aware of these eariler sources.  My question concerns the (possible) relation between Gerono and Lissajous as far as these curves are concerned.

Comment: see also https://mathoverflow.net/q/303023/11260